# How to get the space between separate y axes to appear blank? - Highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I am producing two axis on the same chart using `R`'s `Highcharter` package. I am also using the `hc_theme_flat` theme.

I get strange behaviour depending on whether I use the base `highcharts` plot or the `stock` version:

Base plot:

[image]

Using `type="stock"`:

[image]

The sub graphs appear much more **separate** due to the lack of joining lines.

**How can I recreate this using the base highchart (not stock) function?**

**Example**

```
library(highcharter)

data = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "day"))
data$y = 1
data$y2 = 2

# base
highchart() %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(top = "0%", height = "47%", title = list(text = "y0"), opposite=FALSE, labels = list(format = "£{value}"), min=0),
    list(top = "53%", height = "47%", title = list(text = "y1"), opposite=FALSE, labels = list(format = "£{value}"), offset=0, min=0)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b')) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat(chart = list(backgroundColor = "#FFF"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data, "area", stacking="normal", yAxis = 0, hcaes(x=date, y=y)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data, "area", stacking="normal", yAxis = 1, hcaes(x=date, y=y2))

# type = stock
highchart(type="stock") %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(top = "0%", height = "47%", title = list(text = "y0"), opposite=FALSE, labels = list(format = "£{value}"), min=0),
    list(top = "53%", height = "47%", title = list(text = "y1"), opposite=FALSE, labels = list(format = "£{value}"), offset=0, min=0)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats = list(day = '%d of %b')) %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flat(chart = list(backgroundColor = "#FFF"))) %>%
  hc_add_series(data, "area", stacking="normal", yAxis = 0, hcaes(x=date, y=y)) %>%
  hc_add_series(data, "area", stacking="normal", yAxis = 1, hcaes(x=date, y=y2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the top percentage in the yAxis_multiples statement.  This worked well for me:

hc_yAxis_multiples(
list(top = "0%", height = "40%", title = list(text = "y0"), opposite=FALSE, labels = list(format = "£{value}"), min=0),
list(top = "50%", height = "47%", title = list(text = "y1"), opposite=FALSE, labels = list(format = "£{value}"), offset=0, min=0)) %>%

Play around with the top and height designations to achieve your desired output.

Comment: hi @Jessie, your answer doesnt reproduce the desired result and still ends up with the vertical joining lines. What version of highcharter are you using? (I am on `highcharter * 0.7.0.9001 2020-02-18 [1]`)

Comment: it is also the same on the most recent version `highcharter * 0.8.2`